# Connecting mysql to C++ in VS Code, compiled succesfully but not running

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-code, compilation, libraries

I'm new to databases, so I wanted to make a program to perform simple queries in mysql with C++ in VS Code, in Windows 10. Last time I had problems with linking the library, and now it seems like I managed to fixed them. I have the following code taken from another source by adding my system configurations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/include/mysql.h"

int main(){
    MYSQL* conn;
    conn = mysql_init(0);
    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "password", "project", 0, NULL, 0);

    if(conn){
        std::cout << "Connected" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not connected" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I compile it with the command `g++ main.cpp -Wall -Werror  -I "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/include" -L "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib" -lmysql`, it compiles without reporting any errors. However, if I try to run it, the program simply terminates. I don't understand what problems could be. I suspect the problem might be with mysql connector, but as I said I'm new to it, so I still have doubts. So I would really appreciate it if you could help me out how I can proceed further.

I looked for similar questions, and they helped me only for linking to the library.

Comment: *it compiles without reporting any errors* -- That has no bearing on whether the program has logical bugs.  Second, none of those `cout`'s get printed?  Third, why are you assigning `conn` twice, effectively corrupting the value returned by the `mysql_init(0);` call?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: I took the code from ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876194/vscode-c-mysql-h-undefined-reference-to-mysql-init4```. I just wanted to see if I can compile it first. Well, none of the messages from cout got printed.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Just had to add `libmysql.dll` in a folder with the `main.cpp` file. Thank you all for your advices.

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_init` can return NULL:

> An initialized MYSQL* handler. NULL if there was insufficient memory to allocate a new object.

Wouldn't be safer to check its value before second call?

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. It's more like a comment.

Comment: You can't tell until OP tries.

Comment: Seems more likely that `mysql_real_connect` is failing than there not being enough memory right at the beginning of the program

Comment: If I have to take a guess, mysql_init() is failing b/c no dll in path or access right to create config file or something like this. But a way to solve this is to check return value.